# Is it possible to increase the voltage on 3.3v output to 5v on an ESP board to power a DC motor?

Tags: arduino-motor-shield, electronics, esp32

I am trying to use an ESP32s controller connected to an RC car DC motor. I found that when using my Arduino this is easily accomplished, and I can see that my output pin produces 5v for the motor to spin. My ESP32, however, only produces 3.3v, so of course the motor does not spin. Do I need to use a motor driver board, transistors, or will the ESP32 simply not work in this scenario?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: where are you measuring 1.8v?

Comment: I wrote a simple sketch in my ide that pushes High and low voltage to one of my esp's output pins, with a 1 second delay in between each.

Comment: If you are measuring 1.8v, you are loading the pin beyond it's designed capability.

Comment: yes I should be using a resistor, it was a quick test.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should not power a motor from a micro-controller, period, regardless if that is an ATmega or an ESP32.

Instead, you need to use a motor driver circuit - this isn't really so much about *voltage* amplification, as it is about *current* amplification. The actual I/O output voltage of your ESP32 is likely very close to 3.3v. If you are measuring 1.8v, that is only because you motor is loading the pin so heavily (and improperly) that the voltage sags.

Without the specs of your motor, it's not really possible to provide any specific advice. But you should seek an FET-based solution, not one based on bipolar transistors.  The old bipolar L293D, L298, etc parts are horribly lossy and extremely unsuited to low voltages motors. In some low-voltage, low-current cases, the FET-based TB6612FNG can be a good solution - **but again, this depends entirely on the unstated requirements of your motor**. Typically only very lightweight or weak "RC cars" could use such drive, for more serious ones you should look at hobby-grade Electronic Speed Controller (ESC) modules, or their equivalent circuitry.

These motor driver chips will have two supply inputs. One supplies the logic and would typically share the microcontroller's supply voltage. The other supplies the motors - it might in light duty cases be whatever is supply the microcontroller's regulator, but in more power-hungry cases would often be a unique supply. Both grounds should be connected together and connected to the microcontroller's ground, but in such a way that the ground current for the motors flows directly from the power supply, and never *through* the microcontroller board.

Comment: What I'm actually trying to do, is use an existing circuit's motor driver, and use the esp, to send the signals to it. The existing circuit has it's own 4.8 bat, and I have identified and soldered into the circuit at each point to send power to dc motor(s) L/R/B/F and an additional extended ground wire.  The esp is has its own power and will be the controller. I saw another post where someone was doing this but with an arduino uno (which works). Here are the pictures to the circuit before I soldered into it: https://1drv.ms/f/s!ApWkEol-uDERpBrBrpQp76IVMDuo

Comment: To have a valid question, you need to include the input specifications of what you are driving *in the body of your question*.  External links aren't really acceptable for critical parts of the problem statement.

Comment: Ok. Thanks for your answers. I think I figured out my problem.

Answer (score 2):

I figured out my issue. I was only getting 1.8v output because I was testing my lead after a led light I had plugged in. Once I removed the led, my voltage went to 3.3v, which was expected.

Comment: Then your LED was improperly connected.  Likely you forgot the current limiting resistor, or else you chose an LED and LED current which exceeded the capability of the ESP32.

Comment: Hi Chris, I was being lazy and just forgoing the resistor to test it quickly. Thanks